# I only want to print 1 story from GoogleNews

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-news

I am currently trying to figure out how i could print 1 single story from GoogleNews, now i also have to mention that i am Web Scraping it which makes it even more difficult(i guess). I also tried to google it, but i couldn't really find anything on the internet. So here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

news_url = "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=de&gl=DE&ceid=DE:de"
Client = urlopen(news_url)
xml_page = Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page = soup(xml_page, "xml")
news_list = soup_page.findAll("item")

for news in news_list:
    print(news.title.text)
    print(news.link.text)
    print(news.pubDate.text)
```

So when i run this code, it returns a bunch of stories from today, but i only want to print out 1. story. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using find method as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

news_url = "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=de&gl=DE&ceid=DE:de"
Client = urlopen(news_url)
xml_page = Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page = soup(xml_page, "xml")
news = soup_page.find("item")

#for news in news_list:
print(news.title.text)
print(news.link.text)
print(news.pubDate.text)
```

Or you can use list slicing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

news_url = "https://news.google.com/rss?hl=de&gl=DE&ceid=DE:de"
Client = urlopen(news_url)
xml_page = Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page = soup(xml_page, "xml")
news_list = soup_page.findAll("item")

for news in news_list[:1]:
    print(news.title.text)
    print(news.link.text)
    print(news.pubDate.text)
```

Output:

```
Corona-News-Ticker: Die meisten Ungeimpften wollen ungeimpft bleiben - NDR.de
https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMigQFodHRwczovL3d3dy5uZHIuZGUvbmFjaHJpY2h0ZW4vaW5mby9Db3JvbmEtTmV3cy1UaWNrZXItRGllLW1laXN0ZW4tVW5nZWltcGZ0ZW4td29sbGVuLXVuZ2VpbXBmdC1ibGVpYmVuLGNvcm9uYWxpdmV0aWNrZXIxMzYyLmh0bWzSAQA?oc=5
Thu, 28 Oct 2021 10:56:34 GMT
```

Comment: Oh thanks it worked. I appreciate your help!